# Any disadvantage to defeating Giratina in Distortion World? (Platinum)

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

Playing Pokémon Platinum, I was rather unprepared in going to the Distortion World, and I have very few balls, no trick to get Giratina down to 1HP, etc.
Will there be any disadvantage if I defeat Giratina now and then go get it later via Turnback Cave?

As far as I can make out, the only difference is that Giratina will appear in a different form - but I can find an Orb for him to hold if I want to change this.

Is there any other difference I need to know about?

Comment: I think I got lucky - I managed to catch it anyway, inside half an hour of soft resets. Still, I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As near as I can determine, there are no other differences. If you don't catch Giratina in the distortion world, you can still catch it in Turnback cave later.

Comment: Do you know if the nature gets set from the first fight or does it change each time you battle it in Turnback Cave?

Comment: @Rapida - I don't know; I don't know when legendary pokemon natures are determined normally, and this specific situation is something that's not easily testable without access to savestates.